# get text with whitespaces when generate grammar

Tags: xtext

Is it possible to get a text with whitespaces?

Example rule:

```
rule: 'text' text+=ID+
```

I can obtain the text as a list and could add a whitespace programmatically for each list element, but i don't want that approach. I actually don't need a list. I want one single variable holding the text with whitespaces.

STRING works fine, but it has those ugly quotes, i don't want those quotes as well.

Maybe someone has an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Datatype-Rule like this:

```
rule: 'text' text+= MyText ;

MyText:
    ID+
;
```

Lookup some details in the Reference Documentation in the section [Data Type Rules](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#datatypeRules).

Comment: you are right. when i read out the variable "text" i get the text with whitespaces. can you explain to me why the whitespaces are not hidden although hidden(WS,..) is specified in grammar line?

Comment: The "real" whitespace _is_ hidden, you see only "faked" (aka. "normalized") whitespace. Add a `/* foo */` comment between some words and multiple adjacent whitespaces somewhere else and you will see, that these are stripped out. Note: You still have access to the complete parse tree using `NodeModelUtil`.

Comment: great idea to use the NodeModelUtil. Here i can simply use `node = NodeModelUtils::getNode(rule)` and `NodeModelUtils::getTokenText(node)`